# does jasmine have soft assertion using expect()?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, assertions

In my tests, there are lots of expects.
But some of them may not be severe enough to stop the tests.
Could I ignore the error at a moment and throw them at the end of the test?

Comment: By default, jasmine would not stop once an expectation fails and the execution would continue to the next line..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The jasmine expectations are kind of "soft" by default. In a sense that the *test execution continues after a failure*.

In other words, if you have the following code:

```
expect(true).toBe(false);
expect(false).toBe(true);
```

you would get a test failure with 2 unmet expectations.

---

A common problem is an exact opposite of what you are asking about - how to turn the behavior off so that jasmine would fail the test after the very first expect fails - this is now solved by [`stopSpecOnExpectationFailure` option](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/node.html#section-13) which is `false` by default.